# where I can find the facebook and twitter iphone toolbar icon

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter, icons, toolbar

I am writing an iphone program which use facebook and twitter api.But I can't find any suitable icon to use as toolbar icon. The twitter icon should be a white "t" and the facebook icon should be a white "f",and they must like the responding official logos.thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://findicons.com is a cool resource for icons. If you're looking for official ones, then Twitter actually has downloads on their site that you can use, http://twitter.com/about/files haven't seen equivalent ones for Facebook though, but they might be hidden somewhere on their site..

Comment: thank you all.At last,I made these icons myself using ps.Icons for iphone toolbar are general white and transparent,just like these:

http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=DsS&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=univ&ei=dyUFTLujFMarcbixmPQE&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ct=title&resnum=8&ved=0CEgQsAQwBw&q=iphone%20toolbar%20icon&tbs=isch:1

Answer (score 1):

If Twitter or Facebook don't provide these in their SDK's then you should carefully consider if you are breaking any copyrights, etc. before using their logos. Even if these icons are available "freely" on the internet you might get into various problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2009/06/social-network-icon-pack/